# Why is cis proton coupling larger than trans proton coupling in cyclopropanes?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

In Clayden, Greeves, Warren Organic Chemistry Second Edition Page 815, it states:

> In four- and three-membered rings, *cis* couplings are larger than *trans* ...

but I did not find an explanation for the statement. That being said, why is it true that *cis* coupling is larger than *trans* coupling in cyclopropanes and cyclobutanes? Previously, the textbook stated that coupling is a through-bond effect, not a through-space effect, which led me to reason that the *trans* coupling in cyclopropane should be larger than the *cis* coupling, as in the case of cyclohexane.

Comment: For one there is the normal (Karplus equation-like) coupling across bonds for $^3J_{\mathrm{H-C-H}}$.  Yet, building a model of cyclopropane or cyclobutane shows that hydrogens «on one side» of these plate-like molecules are this much squeezed into proximity that likely there is *additional* coupling *across space* for those sharing the same hemisphere of the cycle which in sum increases the interaction of cisoide H nuclei over their trans interaction.  Higher cycloalkanes are not this much pushed into one conformation, so the through-bond-only coupling is more significant for them.

Comment: @Buttonwood Thank you for the reply. So are you saying that coupling can also occur through space?

Comment: Coupling may occur both across bonds (as seen in multiplet splitting pattern of the typical monodimensional $^1H$-NMR spectrum), and coupling may occur across space; the later is the foundation for H,H-NOESY and H,H-ROESY two-dimensional NMR spectroscopy. The intensity of the corresponding coupling signals through space however decay rapidly over distance r by about 1/(r**6), which is why you need specialized techniques to register them.  Today however they are commonly used in structure elucidation of organic compounds, typically acessed within less than 5 to 10 minutes per sample.